# How to determine the number of bytes necessary to store an uncompressed grayscale image of size 8000 × 3400 pixels?

Tags: image, image-processing

This is all of the information I was provided in the practice question. I am trying to figure out how to calculate it when prompted to do so on an exam...

- How to determine the number of bytes necessary to store an **uncompressed** grayscale image of size 8000 × 3400 pixels?
- I am also curious how the calculation changes if the image is a **compressed** binary image.

Comment: It's impossible to tell without the actual file format you have.

Comment: What's the size of a pixel? How many pixels do you have? Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for a start, your question has much way for improvement.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt This is all of the information I was provided for the practice question. I am trying to figure out how to calculate it when prompted to do so on an exam.

Comment: All bets are off if your image is in PNG format and the data are repetitive.

Comment: Are you in beginners class? If so, then it won't be a tricky question and therefore Mark Ransom's answer is correct for you.

Answer (score 4):

> *"I am trying to figure out how to calculate it when prompted to do so on an exam."*

There are 8 bits to make 1 byte, so once you know how many bits-per-pixel (*bpp*) you have, this is a very simple calculation.

For 8 bits per pixel greyscale, just multiply the width by the height.

```
8000 * 3400 = 27200000 bytes.
```

For 1 bit per pixel black&white, multiply the width by the height and then divide by 8.

```
(8000 * 3400) / 8 = 3400000 bytes.
```

It's critical that the image is uncompressed, and that there's no padding at the end of each raster line.  Otherwise the count will be off.

Comment: For a 16-bit per pixel image 8000 * 3400 * 2 bytes.

Comment: @MarkSetchell true.  I don't often see 16 bit per pixel images.

Comment: @MarkRansom, hope you don't mind the edit but it might clarify for the student.

Comment: In order to clarify it for the students, I think it's better for 8-bit grayscale to have `8000 * 3400 * 8 = 217,600,000 bits  => 217,600,000 / 8 =  27,200,000 bytes` and for 16-bit grayscale to have `8000 * 3400 * 16 = 435,200,000 bits  => 435,200,000 / 8 =  54,400,000‬ bytes`

Comment: @kodfire right you are.  But I like to keep things simple.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to work out is how many pixels you have. That is easy, it is just the width of the image multiplied by the height:

```
N = w * h
```

So, in your case:

```
N = 8000 * 3400 = 27200000 pixels
```

---

Next, in general you need to work out how many samples (S) you have at each of those 27200000 pixel locations in the image. That depends on the type of the image:

- if the image is greyscale, you will have a **single** grey value at each location, so `S=1`
- if the image is greyscale and has transparency as well, you will have a grey value plus a transparency (alpha) value at each location, so `S=2`
- if the image is colour, you will have **three** samples for each pixel - one Red sample, one Green sample and one Blue sample, so `S=3`
- if the image is colour and has transparency as well, you will get the 3 RGB values plus a transparency (alpha) value for each pixel, so `S=4`
- there are others, but let's not get too complicated

---

The final piece of the jigsaw is how **big** each sample is, or how much storage it takes, i.e. the bytes per sample (B).

- 8-bit data takes 1 byte per sample, so `B=1`
- 16-bit data takes 2 bytes per sample, so `B=2`
- 32-bit floating point or integer data take 4 bytes per sample, so `B=4`
- there are others, but let's not get too complicated

So, the actual answer for an uncompressed greyscale image is:

storage required = w * h * S * B

and in your specific case:

```
storage required = 8000 * 3400 * 1 * 1 = 27200000 bytes
```

---

If the image were compressed, the only thing you should hope and expect is that it takes less storage. The actual amount required will depend on:

- how repetitive/predictable the image is - the more predictable the image is, in general, the better it will compress
- how many colours the image contains - fewer colours generally means better compression
- which image file format you require (PNG, JPEG, TIFF, GIF)
- which compression algorithm you use (RLE, LZW, DCT)
- how long you are prepared to wait for compression and decompression - the longer you can wait, the better you can compress in general
- what losses/inaccuracies you are prepared to tolerate to save space - if you are prepared to accept a lower quality version of your image, you can get a smaller file